# How to change font color in mencoder

Tags: fonts, colors, subtitles, mencoder

I'm trying to add hardsubs to an avi using mencoder. I want to change the font color. Googling came up with nothing. Is it not possible to change the color of subtitles using mencoder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using SSA or ASS subs then you need to modify the style definitions within the subtitle file itself.

Comment: What about .srt files?